# Flexmix driver for pscl hurdle model

Tags: r, driver, mixture-model

I've been trying to code in `R` a finite mixture of hurdle models using `pscl`'s `hurdle` implementation. My interest is in particular in the hurdle with negative binomial for the count data.

I've come across the `flexmix` package, which unfortunately does not supply a built-in driver for `pscl`'s `hurdle`. Despite many attempts I haven't been able to correctly code the driver.

Has anyone used `pscl`'s `hurdle` with `flexmix`, and could you share a working implementation of the driver?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the package `countreg` contains this driver. It can be installed from rforge:

```
install.packages("countreg", repos="http://R-Forge.R-project.org")
```

here is the manpage:

http://rpackages.ianhowson.com/rforge/countreg/man/FLXMRnegbin.html

Comment: Thanks for the answer!